# Adding NPM module to Ember app

Tags: ember.js, npm, browserify

I'm trying to use [bootbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootbox) in my Ember app with ember-browserify. I have installed bootbox like a npm module and have added next to code:

```
import Bootbox from 'npm:bootbox';
```

Bu on compilation with ember-cli I got error:

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [object Object] failed with:
Error: Cannot find module 'jquery' from '/Users/Crabar/Documents/Programming/EmberDrinkIt/node_modules/bootbox'
```

Versions: Ember 2.2.0, EmberCLI 2.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import the node module in the **Brocfile.js**?

```
app.import('node_modules/<path_to_module>.js');
```

Comment: I tried to add app.import('node_modules/bootbox.min.js'); but nothing changed. Also, I already have another lib (CryptoJS) imported in similar way and it works.

Comment: Seems that app.import('node_modules/bootbox.min.js') is an unlikely path, more something like **node_modules/bootbox/bootbox.min.js**. Check it once again plz

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But nothing changed with new path.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand why you get the **jquery** error. Have you got jquery installed in the project? if so, it coud be that bootbox needs a specific version of jquery

Comment: I have removed "jquery" from bower.json a week ago according to changelog https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.3.0.

Comment: I never used 2.x sorry. However a nice test would be to add it to the project and see if that solves the import (despite probably breaking other things